# how secure is context in react?

Tags: reactjs

How secure is the context in react, I want to created a user from front end and set his indicial status to demo . later on when the user make a payment his status will change , bottom line is how secure this logic is could someone come and modify the initial set status to 'premium' ? so he could skip the payment part ?

```js
  const Signup = async (email: string, password: string, userType: string) => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        setDoc(doc(db, 'Data', userCredential.user.uid), {
          user: userType,
          verifiedEmail: false,
          status: 'demo',
          createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb and especially for single page applications which are rendered on the client side: Data from and (with)in clients can't and shouldn't be trusted as a security measurement.

So consider the context as "not secure" and always rely on proper permission management on the server side - so the worst thing which can happen is that your client may see the "premium" menus, but can't get anything out of it since the server denies any action.

Comment: problem is I am using firebase and server intervention is minimalistic

Comment: @k90-T Without knowing too much about your application, I can only make broad assumptions. Howsoever: If the features you want to protect are indifferent from the server and you basically just want to sort of limit your frontend's features, you are up for a game of cat-and-mouse (it's pretty much comparable with the DRM struggle game publishers are facing). But I must admit that copy protection stuff, especially for such a use case, isn't my area of expertise and therefore I cannot recommend anything useful.